# Querying for users in a a Role based on Role Id instead of RoleName or DeveloperName

Tags: soql, list, salesforce-id, data, roles

```
 List<User> usrlst = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE UserRole.DeveloperName LIKE : '%Customer_Support_Representative%' and IsActive = True];
```

The problem with this is that we changed the name of the Role and as a result the query did not fetch any users.

We would like to query users based on the UserRole.Id instead of  UserRole.DeveloperName

I understand hardcoding the UserRole.Id is not good practice.

What is the best way to build the list of users based on RoleID such that even when the RoleName/RoleDevelopername changes we don't have to worry about the query failing to fetch data.?

Comment: Store the Profile ID and/or developer name in [custom metadata](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_about.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @DavidCheng -

1. Created  a new Custom Metadata Type Setting (**CMDTS**)
2. Created a field RoleId
3. Created a new record where RecordName = 'Role Name' RoleId = 'copied and pasted roleid'

Queried the **CMDTS** record

```
String CSR_RoleID = [select RoleId__c from Id_Store__mdt Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Support_Rep'].RoleId__c;
     system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>> ' +BDR_RoleID);

    List<User> usrlst = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE UserRole.id = :CSR_RoleID and IsActive = True];

    for (User u : usrlst){

        system.debug('The users in the CSR role are ' +u.Name);
    }
```

**Advantages**

1. When the Label/ Role Name changes for what ever reason, the RoleId will still remain the same.
2. I can keep creating records in CMDTS to store many other Id's. (That's the reason I called the CMDTS 'Id Store' )

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would suggest that the solution is to be aware of the pitfalls of changing the Developer/API name of anything on the platform, and then not to do it.

Change the label by all means, but not the API name, as only problems will ensue. There are plenty of examples where Salesforce themselves have changes the name of something (Wave -> Einstein for example) but haven't touched the API names to avoid breaking loads of stuff.